# HandBrake CLI not working on Linux server using Flatpack - hb_stream_open PATH_TO_FILE failed

Tags: handbrake

Running HandBrakeCLI through flatpack - unable to open any file.

```
flatpak run --filesystem=host --command=HandBrakeCLI fr.handbrake.ghb -i "/var/www/html/mit4mit.co.il/httpdocs/vimeo/drop.avi" -o "/var/www/html/mit4mit.co.il/vimeo/converted.mp4"
Cannot load libnvidia-encode.so.1
[09:47:25] hb_init: starting libhb thread
[09:47:25] thread 7f4d70c25700 started ("libhb")
HandBrake 1.3.1 (2020020500) - Linux x86_64 - https://handbrake.fr
2 CPUs detected
Opening /var/www/html/mit4mit.co.il/httpdocs/vimeo/drop.avi...
[09:47:25] CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30GHz
[09:47:25]  - Intel microarchitecture Broadwell
[09:47:25]  - logical processor count: 2
[09:47:25] hb_scan: path=/var/www/html/mit4mit.co.il/httpdocs/vimeo/drop.avi, title_index=1
disc.c:323: failed opening UDF image /var/www/html/mit4mit.co.il/httpdocs/vimeo/drop.avi
disc.c:424: error opening file BDMV/index.bdmv
disc.c:424: error opening file BDMV/BACKUP/index.bdmv
bluray.c:2585: nav_get_title_list(/var/www/html/mit4mit.co.il/httpdocs/vimeo/drop.avi/) failed
[09:47:25] bd: not a bd - trying as a stream/file instead
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 6.0.1
libdvdread: Encrypted DVD support unavailable.
libdvdread: Can't stat /var/www/html/mit4mit.co.il/httpdocs/vimeo/drop.avi
No such file or directory
libdvdread: Could not open /var/www/html/mit4mit.co.il/httpdocs/vimeo/drop.avi
libdvdnav: vm: failed to open/read the DVD
[09:47:25] dvd: not a dvd - trying as a stream/file instead
[09:47:25] hb_stream_open: open /var/www/html/mit4mit.co.il/httpdocs/vimeo/drop.avi failed
[09:47:25] scan: unrecognized file type
[09:47:25] libhb: scan thread found 0 valid title(s)
No title found.
```

No matter what I do I cannot make HandBrakeCLI find the input file.  I've seen online that the important line here is `hb_stream_open` - all the failures above it are ok.

Answer (score 2):

This is because flatpack is sandboxing it's apps -

[Flatpak docs on sandbox-permissions#filesystem-access](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html#filesystem-access)